# how to fix this error: class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0

Tags: java, macos

I'm really struggling with this. I've been unable to configure Intellij to use Javac, unable to run javadoc. I just can't seem to get my java runtime environment stable and working productively on Mac OSX.

I've created the most basic of examples which is a hello world program and it still errors from command line. Everything I read about this error tells me to "upgrade the compiler". But I'm really not sure what the problem is, the javac & java are both running 1.8 (now, after I tried upgrading the system JVM).

I explicitly set the path when calling javac, checked the version etc. Everything tells me it's 1.8.

Can anyone explain how to fix this? (without reverting my system to a 1.5 SDK).

This is output from the basic hello world application:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac Main.java
Main.java:3: cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
public class Main {
       ^
1 error
localhost:mycompany$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
localhost:mycompany$
```

Output from javac version:

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_45
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Output from java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Is your "output from javac" actually from `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac`?

Comment: yep it's the same. `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -version
javac 1.8.0_45
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message means that you try to load a Java 8 class with a Java 5 VM.

For an unknown reason `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac` is using the JDK 8 Java runtime (`.../rt.jar`) but the compiler itself is loaded with a Java 5 VM.

My next step would be to make sure that `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac` is actually what it should be (and not a script which does something weird). I'd also check the environment (`CLASSPATH`) and options like `-Xbootclasspath`. Try `set | grep -i java` and `set | grep -i path` to look for suspicious variables.

If nothing seems to work, try to reinstall the Java 8 SDK again.

Comment: Thanks I think I fixed it - there was something funny in Java/Extensions folder when I ran it in Verbose mode this entry was in the classpath `/Library/Java/Extensions/bcprov-jdk15-143.jar` - judging by the name I'd say that was the problem, I don't recall what that library is, but I removed all packages from the extensions directly and it's now working...

Comment: That's Bouncy Castle which you need for encryption to work in Java 5. This JAR shouldn't be a problem. My guess is that there was another JAR in there which contained a Java runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same issue with the same versions when trying to build the Arduino IDE using ant. The fix is to remove an old version of **tools.jar** from `/Library/Java/Extensions/` - just wanted to clarify for others that hit the same issue.

Comment: Just had this same problem with Mojave/ but the only files left are /System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar, which looks like it was installed with Mojave. Logically this shouldn't be causing a problem, and everything else is coming from the correct directory. Oh, and this system directory can't be altered even with sudo.